# Fluent nHibernate: why not use lambda expressions in Column()

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

If I want my object to reference a "foo" object using the "foo_key" field I code it like this:

References(x => x.foo)
    .Column("foo_key");

My problem with this is that I much prefer the compile-time safety of fluent, and I hate seeing that hard-coded string "foo_key", when I know that there is a property of that same name.  I would like instead to use this:

References(x => x.foo)
    .Column(x=> x.foo.foo_key);

Am I missing something in Fluent nHibernate?  Should this not be possible, and strongly desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column is not a property, it is the name of the column in the database. It must be a string.